# Connecting two nexus phone via wifi

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi

I am trying to connect two nexus phones via wi-fi (using android socket programming), but it shows me "failed to connect to  (port 8080). connect failed: EHISTUREACH(no route to host)"

however, when I am using a HTC phone and a nexus phone, the connection works nice. I was wondering if anyone have any suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure in both tests, the failing Nexus and the HTC are on the network via WiFi and not the mobile network? I mean, in both cases you have a private address, right?

Comment: Good, I had this feeling about this being a networking problem

Comment: I connected both devices on public network and then tried to run the application. Now I am testing the nexus device in a private network with a seperate router. it's not working

Comment: What are the addresses of both devices?

Comment: right now using 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2

Comment: It should run if both devices are on private network, maybe you should post your question in the networking section of StackExchange.

Comment: ok... I am going to post that in the networking section